# Bug if the name of a rare tag badge is too long

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, tag-badges

I think this doesn't occur very often, but if a tag badge has a very long name and it has been earned at least one year ago, and it shows up in the rare badges, then it doesn't fit, causing a bug:

[image]

Note: This is not my profile. I kept the picture as small as possible to protect the user's privacy.

I have looked around in long tags, and I found at least 15 other such cases, so it is not unique.

**Proposed solution:** If there is a tag badge with more then 20 characters that was awarded more than one year ago, make the rare badge frame of the particular badge type (bronze, silver, gold) larger.

Comment: What site is this happening on?

Comment: @Oded At least on Math. SE, but I think it would happen on any site with long tag names. I checked that Meta.SE doesn't have this problem because the longest tag is ([tag:site-recommendation]) which is only 19 characters.

Comment: @Oded I have also found at least one case of it on Stack Overflow. Several other sides I've checked  don't have the problem. That is quite logical, because smaller sites have less tags and thus less chance for a rare tag badge that is too long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've added some styling rules that will ensure this doesn't happen.

The tags will display with an ellipsis instead of causing the date to drop down:

> [image: badge with ellipsis]

With you in the next build.

Comment: I see. Thank you for solving it.

Comment: By the way, I assume this will be implented on all sites?

Comment: @wythagoras - yes, it will.